# Is a face liquefier a possible weapon?

Tags: weapons

So, say I’m a evil dictator who wants to create fear in the hearts of rebels. Usually, I just cover them in pitch, light them ablaze and throw them down the nearest canyon, but I want to try something new.

I’ve been having my men work on a theoretical weapon called “The Face Liquefier”. The purpose of this weapon is to somehow emit such high temperatures that it causes the victim (Rebel scum)'s face to liquefy and melt off of their skull. My question is, is there a way to make this weapon?

Comment: How do you want this melting to look like? Superheated skin will char way before melting.

Comment: Is your question "Can a flame thrower be used as a weapon?"

Comment: The only thing I can think off is a chemical or virus that liquifies your skin. Heat would just char and burn your face. Its like asking a water filled sponge (which is pretty much consist out of anyway) to liquify under intense heat...

Comment: Have you considered Acid?

Comment: Skin will not melt. Too much heat and you burn and char it. But fat and some other parts will, water boils. So if you splash a rebel with slime around water boiling point. It will come of with chunks of his face.

Comment: "Well to be honest the ray only has evil applications. You know my wife will be happy. She's hated this whole death ray thing from day one." -- Professor Frink

Comment: @Alexander: It doesn’t have to be normal fire heat. Btw, I want the skin on his face to Be turned to good.

Comment: *My question is, is their a way to make this weapon?*  To be frank I don't think anyone should publish information on how to make such a weapon if it was possible.

Comment: Do a search on "acid attack".

Comment: Is it just me, or is this really horrible?

Answer (score 6):

## No

A face will burn before it melts.

Different materials react differently to different temperatures. Every material will melt at a high enough temperate. But some materials will undergo [autoignition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature) before they melt. A material that auto-ignites must be able to sustain a oxidation chain reaction in air in order to stay on fire. That is, once the material auto-ignites, the oxidation reaction of the material with oxygen in air must be exothermic, so that the reaction causes a follow-on auto-ignition in nearby molecules.

Materials like metals without highly exothermic oxidation reactions will melt into a liquid before the 'burn' in oxygen. But organic materials, generally, will ignite and carry out exothermic reactions. Carbon reacts with oxygen to make carbon dioxide, hydrogen to make water, and nitrogen to make various nitrogen oxides. All these 'burning' reactions will happen at a lower temperature than the melting point of the organic materials that make up the human body, like collagen or keratin or live cells.

For a living creature, the water must be driven off before temperatures will rise enough to auto-ignite, but the fact that creatures are ~75% water means their temperature will stay in the range of 100 C (the boiling point of water) until all the water is driven off. Once the water is driven off, the organics will auto-ignite with increased thermal energy, before they melt.

Answer (score 3):

**Superheated Steam**

If you had a flame thrower like device that fired super heated steam, it could have that sort of effect.

It would cook any exposed flesh and would cause it to peel off the bone

Comment: Or a stream of superheated nitrogen?  By displacing any oxygen, you *may* be able to prevent autoignition (As mentioned in [kingledion's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/130964/47510), this is the biggest source of "nope" to the concept)

Answer (score 2):

**Kind of**, probably not by heat, but by **chemical** changes (or something physical or biological that affects chemical structure).

There are [collagenases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagenase) and [matrix metalloproteinase (or matrixins)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_metalloproteinase), capable of breaking down the collagen that bonds cells of skin and other tissues. Gas gangrena bacteria uses a collagenase ([photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_gangrene#/media/File:Gas_gangrene.jpg)) and snake and other lifeforms uses matrixins ([photo](https://www.nejm.org/na101/home/literatum/publisher/mms/journals/content/nejm/1997/nejm_1997.336.issue-17/nejm199704243361719/production/images/img_small/nejm199704243361719_f1.jpeg)).

Going more "Doctor Who"-ish one can imagine another technology that makes a similar effect at distance… Something like microwaves resonating to collagen specific frecuencies, or nanobots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impose the psychological shock of a rebel militant losing his face, you can go one of two ways.  The facial skin and muscles can definitely be ripped off by force, resulting in a face that looks like Red Skull from the Captain America movie.  I recall someone being attacked by a chimpanzee this way:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3DeJjHAz8I
Thus your weapon can be some type of nanobot swarm that quickly cuts all the rebel's facial tendons, muscles, and skin.  Or you can shock someone by blanking out all his facial features while still allowing him to eat and breathe.  That can be accomplished by applying a thick layer of super strong glue to his face.

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Photoshop is the best way and you won’t be arrested. Simply begin program and choose a picture of such hero called “rebel scum” and then use your mouse to choose from the available columns. One such colum is called, ‘liquify’. Spend time experimenting and reinstalling image. As it is obvious you might be obsessed with the rebel scum you wish to torture.